# How do I correctly add custom fonts to my HTML code?

Tags: html

I am working on an HTML project for school, and I'm trying to add a custom font from Google Fonts. After selecting the font I wanted, Google gave me the code to add to my project to be able to get the font, but I'm getting an error. The error says, "Named entity expected. Got none." Below is the code I'm using for the title of my webpage.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Monsieur+La+Doulaise&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style> font-family: 'Monsieur La Doulaise', cursive;
    </style>
    <title><span>The Oasis</span></title>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp You need to apply it to an element. The w3schools shows it applied to a p tag.... If you want it for the entire page, apply  it to the body tag. CSS 101

Answer (score 0):

Invalid HTML and style definition

1. Title does not have markup
2. You need to wrap your font statement so it applies to an element in the body [CSS Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax)

Your validator is overly strict.

This code will validate here https://validator.w3.org/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>The Oasis</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Monsieur+La+Doulaise&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    h3 {
      font-family: 'Monsieur La Doulaise', cursive;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h3>The Oasis</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because `&` is a special character in HTML: It starts an entity. In older versions of HTML following it with text that wasn't the name of an entity was an error. HTML 5 is more forgiving. The tool you are using to error check your HTML expects you to replace it with `&amp;` (the named entity for an ampersand character).

In addition:

- `font-family: 'Monsieur La Doulaise', cursive;` is a CSS **rule**, you need to put it inside a **rule-set** (which tells the browser which element(s) to apply it to).
- You need an element to apply it to (your example code lacks the mandatory `<body>` element and any content that would be displayed in it).
- `<span>` elements are forbidden inside `<title>` elements (as are all other elements).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Monsieur+La+Doulaise&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    p {
      font-family: 'Monsieur La Doulaise', cursive;
    }
  </style>
  <title>The Oasis</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Example</p>
</body>

</html>
```

This is really pretty basic stuff. You should probably read [an introductory guide to CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps) before trying to solve specific problems with the tool.

Comment: @mplungjan I understand your code and where the code went wrong, but the code for the font is what I copied directly from Google Fonts, and I want the title of my webpage to be the custom font I chose.

Comment: @ScullCandy65 — The title is used in the browser title bar, the default bookmark name, and the browser tab. Those are browser UI features and **cannot** be influenced by CSS. And I'm not mplungjan.

Comment: I understand that now, but then how would I change the font of the title for my webpage, because I know that for a story I'm writing in Google Docs, I set the title to look like this,











I̸̡̘̪͔̠̺̗͐͋̚͘n̸̻͖̘͖̭͆̌̉͌̏̈̚͝f̴̧̢̆̑̇̏̀̋̆̾̚͝i̴̡̪̭͕̯̩̖̒̋̾͋̎̚͠͝ͅň̸̡̳̤̰̳͕̜͂̇̏̈ĭ̴̡̢̦͇̺̖͍̬̖̲̃̚͠͝t̸͖̣͕͙͈̦͔̲͚͗̄̀̀̄͋̍͘͜y̸͚̗͍͔̦̹̮͓͂̓̈͌͆ ̸͙̊̽́͋̀̌͌̑B̶̡͎̗̭̍̂͛̀̒̽͌̚̕é̵̻͚̟͕̮y̴̢̡̺͈͙̖̤̮͚͌ȍ̵̧̫̳̓̊̀̓͆̉́̊͝ͅṅ̶͚̱̖͙̜͒͜d̷̨̦̞͉̯́͆̒͗͆͠


and Google Docs displays this same exact text in my tab.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the main heading of the page (which should be an `<h1>` element in the `<body>`) with the `<title>` (which is not rendered in the page at all as I previously mentioned). (Re edit of previous comment): Using obscure characters is different from changing the font.

Comment: OMG, I'm so dumb. I just figured out what all you were saying to me.